# Android Studio creates only 'Empty Activity' projects

Tags: android

All the sudden today Android Studio meshes up any new project I create except the 'Empty Activity' projects. I uninstalled and reinstalled AS, but no luck. Below is a screenshot of what meant to be a project from 'Basic Activity'. Any suggestions?
[image]

Below you can see the messages tab:

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
D:\Programming\Kotlin\Test\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(19) error: resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka com.gmail.mosestak.myapplication:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
Error:(19) resource style/AppTheme.NoActionBar (aka com.gmail.mosestak.myapplication:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar) not found.
Error:failed processing manifest.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Failed to execute aapt
>   Information:BUILD FAILED in 46s
>   Information:7 errors
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Comment: can you post the full error log

Comment: What are the 7 errors?

Comment: The 7 errors are listed above in my edited post

Answer (score 0):

Since I found no solution, I performed a full uninstall including all the registry entries and preferences with a 3d party uninstaller and reinstalled everything. Now it seems to work fine. Still have no idea what caused all this mess.